# AngularJs: Call a JSON file whos URL is in other JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json

I have three JSON files.

```
uiControl.json: Will Dynamically create FORM with label/input/select
```

CREATES2MDMHEADERJSON.json: will fill data in the label/input/or select option
S2MDEALTYPEJSON.json: will fill data in the dropdown(Dynamically)

`http://plnkr.co/edit/zftzjy10J6lITs5vM0iM`

I want to push different JSON file in dropDown based on uiControl.field[0].dropdown value.

Comment: I resolved, thanks